# Javassist : Accessing internal methods of a declared method

Tags: java, javassist

I am trying to create a code injection scenario using javassist. In this case, I need to access the inner methods of a method which exists and then add an "insertBefore" and "insertAfter" just over/below that nested method.

I am able to call the .class file of the program using `CtClass` and the (outer) method using `CtMethod`. Is there any way to access a method say `X` which is called from this method. I need to inject some code just before this.

For example:

```
public class Example{

    public void onCreate() {
        //something
    }

    public void A()
    {
        //something
        //insertBefore should go here
        startDoingX(i);     <---------method X
        //insertAfter should go here
    }

}
```

Is there a sub-clause of `CtMethod`, which will help me get access to `startDoingX` method so that I can inject code before/after it?

Comment: These aren't "inner methods" (lamda expressions?). These are 
**method calls**.

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman : Apologies. Yes, method calls is what I meant.